# Can i user instance method in JPA entity?

Tags: jpa

```
public class Dept{
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private String address;
 private List<Student> students;

 public static List <Student> getStudentByDeptid(EntityManager em, Dept dept)
{
        ..............
}
}
```

getStudentByDeptid() should be static or non static?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you shouldn't `JPA` entity are not designed to have business logic in them you should use `Session Bans` for the same. You can define a `StudentBean` as session bean and define this logic in that bean.

Assuming you are calling query on em passed to function.